# I dont know how to go about looping a specific part of my code

Tags: python, function, loops

I'm writing a casino-based game and I'm having some trouble with coding blackjack, I run into a problem where you only have the option to "hit" once, and I'm not sure how to make it loop. Once you've "hit" it just settles with your score as if it was final even tho you might still be far under 21. Every time I try to fix it some other part of the code just breaks.

(keep in mind this is not the full code but just the blackjack part)

```
import os
import random

deck = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]*4
bal = 100
balstr = str(bal) + "$"

def clear():
    os.system('cls')

def deal(deck):
    hand = []
    for i in range(2):
        random.shuffle(deck)
        card = deck.pop()
        if card == 11:card = "J"
        if card == 12:card = "Q"
        if card == 13:card = "K"
        if card == 14:card = "A"
        hand.append(card)
    return hand

def newRound():
    again = input("Do you want to play again? (Y/N): ").lower()
    if again == "y":
        blackjack()
    else:
        #takes you back to main menu in the full code, just ignore this
        position()

def total(hand):
    total = 0
    for card in hand:
        if card == "J" or card == "Q" or card == "K":
            total+= 10
        elif card == "A":
            if total >= 11: 
                total+= 1
            else: total+= 11
        else:
            total += card
    return total

def hit(hand):
    card = deck.pop()
    if card == 11:
        card = "J"
    if card == 12:
        card = "Q"
    if card == 13:
        card = "K"
    if card == 14:
        card = "A"
    hand.append(card)
    return hand

def currentHands(dealerHand, playerHand):
    clear()
    print(("The dealer has a ") + str(dealerHand) + " for a total of " + str(total(dealerHand)))
    print(("You have a ") + str(playerHand) + " for a total of " + str(total(playerHand)))

def score(dealerHand, playerHand, usrbetint):
    global bal

    if total(playerHand) == 21 or total(dealerHand) > 21 or total(playerHand) > total(dealerHand) and total(playerHand) < 21:
        currentHands(dealerHand, playerHand)
        bal += usrbetint
        print("Congratulations, you win!\n \nYour new balance is {}$".format(bal))
    else :
        currentHands(dealerHand, playerHand)
        bal -= usrbetint        
        print("Sorry, you lose.\n \nYour new balance is {}$".format(bal))

    
def blackjack():
    choice = 0
    clear()
    print("Let's play blackjack!\n")
    userbet = input("(for help type help) How much money do you want to use: ").upper()
    if userbet == "HELP" :
        if userbet == "HELP" :
            print("Instructions")
        else :
            print("Something went wrong")
            pass
    else :
        usrbetint = int(userbet)
    dealerHand = deal(deck)
    dealerHandShow = [dealerHand[0]]
    dealerHandShow = total(dealerHandShow)
    playerHand = deal(deck)
    print(("The dealer is showing a ") + str(dealerHand[0]) + " for a total of " + str(dealerHandShow))
    print(("You have a ") + str(playerHand) + " for a total of " + str(total(playerHand)))
    choice = input("Do you want to [H]it or [S]tand?: ").lower()
    clear()
    if choice == "h":
        hit(playerHand)
        while total(dealerHand) < 17:
            hit(dealerHand)
        score(dealerHand, playerHand, usrbetint)
        newRound()
    elif choice == "s":
        while total(dealerHand) < 17:
            hit(dealerHand)
        score(dealerHand, playerHand, usrbetint)
        newRound()

blackjack()
```

i assume the fix would be somewhere around the last 20 lines of the "blackjack" function but didnt know how to explain everything without sending the clump of code.

If someone please could give me tips on where to change stuff i'd really appreciate that and ignore the "global bal" part, it was the only way i knew to add a truly global variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you don't know how many times you'll be looping (it is based on user input), you probably want a `while` loop. Your current code mixes the dealer behavior into the player handling, you you'll need to separate that out, since we don't want to loop it.

```
print("You have a " + str(playerHand) + " for a total of " + str(total(playerHand)))
choice = input("Do you want to [H]it or [S]tand?: ").lower()
while choice == "h":
    clear()
    hit(playerHand)
    print("You have a " + str(playerHand) + " for a total of " + str(total(playerHand)))
    choice = input("Do you want to [H]it or [S]tand?: ").lower()

while total(dealerHand) < 17:
    hit(dealerHand)

score(dealerHand, playerHand, usrbetint)
```

You might want to add an additional condition to stop asking the player if they want to hit when they've already busted.

Comment: youre a legend dude